# FindFit for all columns of a matrix

Tags: matrix, fitting, parametric-functions, variable

I have a table of dimensions {10,3} say. Each column is the value of some function f(x,a) wrt to x and the parameter $a~ ( =1,2,3$ say) refers to the columns. So for example if we let

$f(x,a) = a \sin(x)$ then the first column of my matrix contains values $$1\cdot \sin(x), (\text{where }x=1,...10)$$
second column 
$$2\cdot \sin(x)$$

and so on. Obviously one can use `FindFit` to force Mathematica find a fit to the data point in say column 1. One can repeat this for the other columns. But is there a simple way to use `FindFit` to find fits to each column?

In the above example suppose I save the data of column 1 in a variable named columnOne: I would write for that particular column

```
fitPAR = 
  FindFit[columnOne, 
   a*Sin[b*x], {a, b}, x];
fitColumnOne[x_] = a*Sin[b*x], {a, b} /. fitPAR;
```

and as an output I should obtain that

```
fitColumnOne[x_] = 1*Sin[1*x].
```

How can one automatize this to apply to each column of a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = Table[a Sin[x], {x, 1, 10}, {a, 1, 3}];

rules = FindFit[#, a*Sin[b*x], {a, b}, x]& /@ Transpose @ data
```

> {{a -> 1., b -> 1.}, {a -> 2., b -> 1.}, {a -> 3., b -> 1.}}

```
ReplaceAll[#][a*Sin[b*x]]& /@ rules
```

> {1. Sin[1. x], 2. Sin[1. x], 3. Sin[1. x]}

Comment: Nice solution, thanks!

Comment: This works very nicely but Mathematica gives a warning regarding `ReplaceAll[#][a*Sin[b*x]]& /@ rules` that too few arguments in expr/.rules. Anyway to avoid this warning? The code still works though.

Comment: The above example does not give a warning at this step. It has to do something with your data, or with some interfering definitions.

Comment: OK I'll check again. It says ´too few arguments´.